# comment per page settings

Tags: comments

How can I change "Default comments per page" array to my own. What hook I need to use, if it needed?
`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state)`
with `FORM_ID = node_type_form`

$form doesn't contain this value

Answer (score 4):

Drupal pulls the number of comments per page from `variable_get('comment_default_per_page' . $node->type)`.   Its default is 50.  To change this go to content type X -> edit, then save.

To change the 50 to something else, you can create you own custom module and have this code

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'node_type_form' && isset($form['comment'])) {
        $form['comment']['comment_default_per_page']['#default_value'] = 70;
    }   
}
```

[image: Comment setting for a node content type]

If you want to change it somewhere else,  then I recommend calling `variable_set('comment_default_per_page' . $node->type,  'MYVALUE')`.  See below where it is hard-coded
inside comment.module & comment_form:

```
$form['comment']['comment_default_per_page'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Default comments per page'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('comment_default_per_page_'. $form['#node_type']->type, 50),
  '#options' => _comment_per_page(),
  '#description' => t('Default number of comments for each page: more comments are distributed in several pages.'),
);


function _comment_get_display_setting($setting, $node) {
  global $user;

  if (isset($_GET[$setting])) {
    $value = $_GET[$setting];
  }
  else {
    // get the setting's site default
    switch ($setting) {
      case 'mode':
        $default = variable_get('comment_default_mode_'. $node->type, COMMENT_MODE_THREADED_EXPANDED);
        break;
      case 'sort':
        $default = variable_get('comment_default_order_'. $node->type, COMMENT_ORDER_NEWEST_FIRST);
        break;
      case 'comments_per_page':
        $default = variable_get('comment_default_per_page_'. $node->type, 50);
    }
...
```

and inside `comment_render($node, $cid = 0) {`

```
$comments_per_page = _comment_get_display_setting('comments_per_page', $node);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it's working fine for D7,, but you forgot to add underscore before the content type.. the correct is: variable_set('comment_default_per_page_' . $node->type, 'MYVALUE')

Answer (score 0):

The default comments per page is stored and changed on the content type itself. In D6 it was stored using `variable_set()` but I'm not sure if this is the case for D7.